# Failed to find the MSVC compiler version 10.0 on your system

Tags: python, pyside, windows-8.1

Trying to install PySide and I am getting this error:

```
running build

Python architecture is 64bit

nmake not found. Trying to initialize the MSVC env...

Searching MSVC compiler version 10.0

error: Failed to find the MSVC compiler version 10.0 on your system.
```

I have minGW, QT 4.8 vs 2010 and mingw versions, Cmake.

Now I have a feeling that something is missing from my PATH, but I'm not sure where and what should it point. My current PATH:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit version of VS2010?

Comment: I find it really confusing to be honest, do I need the whole dev kit (500mb) or just redistribution package ? For the record I have this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555 and it does include x64 version.

Comment: PySide 1.2.1 windows binaries for Python 3.4 are now available for download http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your comment you have the redistributable package for VS2010. This installs the runtime components that are needed for applications built with VS2010.

However, the error message you show indicates that the module you are trying to install requires the C++ compiler from VS2010. Presumably that's because you are attempting to install from source.

Compounding your misery you have 64 bit Python which requires a 64 bit version of the C++ compiler. Such a thing does exist, but it's not available easily for free. The free Express versions of VS have moved on to VS2013 now. It's hard to come by a download for the 2010 Express. And in any case, that never shipped with a 64 bit compiler.

You could obtain the 64 bit VS2010 compiler from the Windows SDK of the day, and that's how I personally obtained it. In fact I closely guard the installer for that version of the SDK so that I will always have access to the 64 bit VS2010.

Frankly I think you'd be best off installing a binary version rather than from source. The best source of these is the [wonderful site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) maintained by [Christoph Gohlke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453463/cgohlke). Although he's not yet updated the PySide downloads with one for Python 3.4 so in this case you'll be stymied.

I also note that the PySide site has a good set of [Windows binary downloads](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows). But again, not for Python 3.4. Perhaps you are just a little bit too close to the bleeding edge of progress for your own good. You might be well advised to back off to Python 3.3 until all the third party developers can catch up. After all, Python 3.4 only hit the tubes a fortnight ago.

Comment: I did try to install it on 32 bit 3.3.5 Python via pip, still got the same error. Now the binary install worked just fine so thank you for that, it's just still peculiar what's wrong with my system.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your system. You just don't have the compiler to build from source. That's normal.

Comment: If you are installing via pip, you should use --use-wheel parameter, the install instructions for windows are here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#installing-pyside-on-a-windows-system. Official binaries for Python 3.4 will be available soon.

Comment: and BTW, the PyPI site contains detailed instructions on howto build PySide on windows (no need for Visual Studio Express, only Windows SDK is required), please see here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#building-pyside-on-a-windows-system

Answer (score 1):

This [site](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/pyside/) has more extensive download for PySide binary version.